# how to return zero instead of null from a subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a query which I want to return 0 when null is returned FROM the subquery, i used the IFNULL function, but i still get null at the end. Below is a similar query, please help, dont know what to do. (PS: I used a phone to write this so mu formating might appear bad, sorry)

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.Amount, t1.parent, 
      ( SELECT @Total := IFNULL(SUM(t2.amount), 0) AS amount FROM transactions t2 WHERE t1.`id` = t2.parent GROUP BY t2.parent ) AS AmountRepaid, 
      ( SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(SUM(t3.amount) AS DECIMAL) > CAST(t1.amount AS DECIMAL) THEN "Over" WHEN CAST(SUM(t3.amount) AS DECIMAL) = CAST(t1.amount AS DECIMAL) THEN "Complete" ELSE "Incomplete" END FROM transactions t3 WHERE t1.`id` = t3.Parent GROUP BY t3.Parent ) AS PaymentStatus 
      FROM transactions t1 WHERE t1.`Parent` IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use following way:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.Amount, t1.parent, 
       @Total := IFNULL( ( SELECT SUM(t2.amount) AS amount FROM transactions t2 WHERE t1.`id` = t2.parent GROUP BY t2.parent ), 0) AS AmountRepaid,
```

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge: You use `GROUP BY` in your subquery so in this case this subquery can return 0 rows (if there are no `t1.id = t2.parent`) so `@Totall` is NULL in this case. `Group BY` here is useless because of WHERE condition you always select only one group. So you can remove GROUP BY to use your query or use way from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.Amount, t1.parent, 
   IF(SUM(t2.amount) IS NULL, 0 ,SUM(t2.amount)) AS amount FROM transactions t2 WHERE t1.`id` = t2.parent GROUP BY t2.parent ) AS AmountRepaid, 
  ( SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(SUM(t3.amount) AS DECIMAL) > CAST(t1.amount AS DECIMAL) THEN "Over" WHEN CAST(SUM(t3.amount) AS DECIMAL) = CAST(t1.amount AS DECIMAL) THEN "Complete" ELSE "Incomplete" END FROM transactions t3 WHERE t1.`id` = t3.Parent GROUP BY t3.Parent ) AS PaymentStatus 
  FROM transactions t1 WHERE t1.`Parent` IS NULL;
```